# Can I add material design components to react native project?

Tags: react-native, material-design

Is there any way I can add material design components to react native projects?

I didn't find, how to install it on react-native project.

[Material Design](https://material.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add material designing component into react native. There are some libraries available which provide cross-platform compatibility of material designing components into android and ios.

Please check these links

https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui

https://medium.com/@victorvarghese/super-cool-material-ui-components-in-react-native-dd7c4434bc26

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-material-design

https://github.com/madhavanmalolan/awesome-reactnative-ui

**!! If you want to use specific native material designing component which library is not available at this time so you need to write native module code in android and ios and bridge that code into react native !!**